# How to remove/hide time from jQuery DateTimePicker, Asp Net

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, time, datetimepicker

I removed the time selection in the calendar widget and the start date in the fields also without time.
But the main problem is that when you select a date, the current time is still inserted in the field. Need only to display the date, without the time.

cshtml

```
<div class="form-group">
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.DateTo, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
<div class="col-md-10">
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DateTo, "{0:d}", new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DateTo, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
</div>
```

js

```
$("#DateTo").datetimepicker({
    timepicker: false,
    pickTime: false,
    closeOnDateSelect: true,
    dateFormat: "yy/mm/dd"
});
```

Model

```
[Display(Name = "DateTo", ResourceType = typeof(Resources.Resource))]
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd.MM.yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
[Required]
public DateTime DateTo { get; set; }
```

jQuery DateTimePicker plugin v2.4.5
If there are simple alternative widgets for asp net, please advise.

Answer (score 0):

To display only the date without the time, just do it this way:

```
$("#DateTo").datepicker({ 
   dateFormat: "yy/mm/dd",
   closeOnDateSelect: true
});
```

Because you're going through .datetimepicker where it picks up date and time, .datepicker picks up only thedate.